# Error returning structure from dll function in python

Tags: python, function, dll, structure, ctypes

I have a dll written in C exporting this function:

```
typedef struct testResult_t {
    int testId;
    int TT; 
    double fB;
    double mD;
    double mDL;
    int nS;
    int nL;
} TestResult;

TestResult __stdcall dummyTest(){
    TestResult a = {0};
    a.testId = 3;
    return a;
};
```

I'm calling the function from python this way:

```
class TestResult(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("testId", c_int),
        ("TT", c_int),
        ("fB", c_double),
        ("mD", c_double),
        ("mDL", c_double),
        ("nS", c_int),
        ("nL", c_int)
    ]

astdll.dummyTest.restype = TestResult
result = astdll.dummyTest()
print "Test ID: %d" % (result.testId)
```

I'm getting this error while executing the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ast.py", line 330, in <module>
    main()
  File "ast.py", line 174, in main
    result = astdll.dummyTest()
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 941, in GetResult
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Any Idea what's the problem?

Comment: You should show everything. You have omitted vital details. We cannot see what `astdll` is. A bigger problem is that different C compilers have different ABIs for returning large structs. Notably MSVC and GCC have a different ABI for your function. Returning the struct using a reference parameter, ctypes.byref, is the best way to design this interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem (Windows 7 x64, 32-bit Python 2.7.3).  I'll describe what I tried in order to reproduce your problem, in the hope that it will help you.

I created a new project and solution in Visual C++ Express 2008, both named "CDll".  The project was set to compile as C code and use the stdcall calling convention.  Apart from the stuff VC++ 2008 autogenerated, it had the following two files:

CDll.h:

```
#ifdef CDLL_EXPORTS
#define CDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define CDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

typedef struct testResult_t {
    int testId;
    int TT; 
    double fB;
    double mD;
    double mDL;
    int nS;
    int nL;
} TestResult;

TestResult CDLL_API __stdcall dummyTest();
```

CDll.cpp (yes, I know the extension is '.cpp', but I don't think that matters):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CDll.h"

TestResult __stdcall dummyTest() {
    TestResult a = {0};
    a.testId = 3;
    return a;
};
```

I then compiled and built the DLL.  I then attempted to load it and call the function with the following Python script:

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_int, c_double, windll

astdll = windll.CDll

class TestResult(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("testId", c_int),
        ("TT", c_int),
        ("fB", c_double),
        ("mD", c_double),
        ("mDL", c_double),
        ("nS", c_int),
        ("nL", c_int)
    ]

astdll.dummyTest.restype = TestResult
result = astdll.dummyTest()
print "Test ID: %d" % (result.testId)
```

When I ran this script I got the output `Test ID: 3`.

---

The first thought I had about what your problem might be was that you were attempting to load the DLL using `CDLL` when you should be using `windll`, but when I tried using `CDLL`, I got a completely different error message.  You haven't shown us how you are loading the DLL, but I suspect you are using `windll` as I have done above.

Comment: That was the problem, I was using oledll to load the library. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Jorge Do beware that your function will only be callable from compilers that use the MS large struct return value ABI.

Comment: Luke, can you please take a look on my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773602/returning-struct-from-c-dll-to-python) ? It's very similar problem, difference is that I have strings in my struct, it gives me headache for days