# Returning struct from c++ dll to Python

Tags: c++, python, struct, ctypes, dllexport

I'm trying to return structure so I can use it in Python. I am beginner programmer so please explain me what am I doing wrong. I've succeeded to return simple ctypes earlier (bool, unsigned int) but struct is too complicated for me. This is what I have:

DLLAPI.h

```
#define DLLAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
...
DLLAPI myStruct* DLLApiGetStruct();
```

DLLAPI.cpp

**EDIT1: instead of TString, struct members type is wchar_t* now, but error I get is the same**

```
...
typedef struct myStruct{
    wchar_t* id; 
    wchar_t* content; 
    wchar_t* message;
} myStruct;

DLLAPI myStruct* DLLApiGetStruct(){
    myStruct* test = new myStruct();
    test->id = _T("some id"); 
    test->content = _T("some content"); 
    test->message = _T("some message");
    return test;
}
```

here is my Python code:

```
...
class TestStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("id", c_wchar_p),
        ("content", c_wchar_p),
        ("message", c_wchar_p)
        ]
class SomeClass(object):
    ....  
    def test(self):
        myDLL = cdll.LoadLibrary('myDLL.dll')
        myDLL.DLLApiGetStruct.restype = TestStruct
        result = myDLL.DLLApiGetStruct()
        print "result type: ", type(result)
        print "-"*30
        print "result: ",result
        print "-"*30
        print result.id # line 152
```

this is what I get:

```
    result type:  <class 'Foo.TestStruct'>
    ------------------------------
    result:  <Foo.TestStruct object at 0x027E1210>
    ------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ....
    ....
    ....
    line 152, in test
        print result.id
    ValueError: invalid string pointer 0x00000002
```

TString I've used is std::wstring

Should type in myStruct be pointers or something instead TString?
Please help me, I've spend 5 days trying to make this work.

Comment: @eryksun you are my hero :D please post this as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the others explained, the problem with version 1 of the question is the use of std::string which is not a valid type for interop.

Looking at version 2 of the question, your C++ and Python declarations do not match. The C++ code returns a pointer to the struct, but the Python code expects the struct to be returned by value.

You could change either C++ or Python to match the other.

**C++**

```
DLLAPI myStruct DLLApiGetStruct()
{
    myStruct result;
    result.id = L"some id";
    result.content = L"some content";
    result.message = L"some message";  
    return result;
}
```

**Python**

```
myDLL.DLLApiGetStruct.restype = POINTER(TestStruct)
```

Obviously you must apply only one of these changes!

Note that in the C++ code I chose to use explicit wide strings with the L prefix rather than the _T() macro. The former matches wchar_t* and the latter is what you use with TCHAR. I would not recommend TCHAR these days, unless you need to support Win98.

Comment: I've changed Python code and it works fine now, thank you.
I've also tried changing c++ code as you suggested (return struct by value) but I can't build dll...I get `error C2526: 'DLLApiGetStruct' : C linkage function cannot return C++ class 'myStruct'`

Comment: Returning large structs by value is a shady area. Different compilers have different ways to do it. Can be troublesome. Should have said so in answer.

Comment: @Aleksandar: The compiler doesn't know that it's plain old data (POD). I think it will compile successfully if you move the definition of `myStruct` into the header before the `DLLApiGetStruct` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/ctypes.html

`c_wchar_p` contains `wchar_t *`, not `std::wstring`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, is it even possible to receive string  in Python this way? Can you please give me example of how to do that?

Comment: please take a look on **EDIT1**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are returning a structure containing `std::string`'s but you are telling Python that the types are pointers to wchar_t. This has the same effect as doing the following in C++.

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string id; 
    std::string content; 
    std::string message;
};

struct Bar
{
    wchar_t* id; 
    wchar_t* content; 
    wchar_t* message;
};

Foo f;
Bar* = reinterpret_cast<Bar*>(&f);
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. I've tried what you suggested, is this ok?:
I've put `struct Bar` in DLLAPI.cpp and changed DLLAPI Bar* DLLApiGetStruct(){ ..... Bar* barStruct= reinterpret_cast<Bar*>(&test);
return barStruct;` 
I get the same error in Python.

Comment: to avoid `reinterpret_cast` I've simply changed my struct member types to `wchar_t*` , take a look on **EDIT1**